# Incorrect positioning of phrase "accept or start bounty"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See image from my roster of questions

[image]

Now, I don't know if you can see it, but the phrase "Have you considered..." is above the gray separator, so that it looks like it's the question the phrase is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

The message pictured above will now be above the question it goes with, well inside the grey border, being much clearer about which question it belongs to.